# Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider error encountered when launching app to device on debug mode xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) library in order to use firebase in my xamarin forms app. However after I completed the android set up, I encounter the runtime error

> "05-12 10:41:01.362 E/AndroidRuntime( 4616): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f080010".

I changed my output verbosity to detailed and found this in the build message

> 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Firebase.Common.60.1142.0\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Firebase.Common.targets')) was evaluated as (!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Firebase.Common.60.1142.0\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Firebase.Common.targets')).
>
> 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.60.1142.0\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.targets')) was evaluated as (!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.60.1142.0\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.targets')).
>
> 1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.60.1142.0\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.targets')) was evaluated as (!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.60.1142.0\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.targets')).

I've no idea what's causing this or the effect of it is.

In runtime I see this message in the output

> 05-12 10:40:51.334 W/ResourceType( 4616): For resource 0x7f080010, entry index(16) is beyond type entryCount(14)

It seems like a dex limit issue but I've already tried enabling multidex to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can use Firebase like [this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I got this issue after Promoting my Android Target API from 21 to 26.

=> Remove previously installed application from the device.

=> Clean and Rebuild

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a valid solution but I re-enabled multidex, and cleaned the solution, physically deleting the bin & obj files for the local projects and the PCL. After a couple of rebuilds, it just started working.

I'd like to post this for other people encountering this and if anyone can offer a solid explanation I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

Using MvvmCross we use a `LinkerPleaseInclude` class which is just a simple class where we add code implementations that may be linked out.

In that class I simply added:

```
public void Include(Firebase.Provider.FirebaseInitProvider provider)
{
    Console.WriteLine(provider);
}
```

Now it is not linked out and works every time.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appeared when I enabled Proguard. If you have Proguard enabled in the Android settings you must create a file called `Proguar.cfg` and add it to your project, in the properties you must select ProguardCofiguration in the compilation actions.

[image]

Then my solution was to add these instructions in my `Proguar.cfg` file.

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Also the weight of my apk file decreased a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.
1.Clean your project.
2.Then rebuild.

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the package name in google-services.json and package name in firebase is different, i was facing same issue, later i read about firebaseinitprovider method turns out it takes data from google-services.json and compared it with data in firebase. if there is any mismatch it will simply throw a error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the below permissions in AndroidManifest. I had the same error and this resolved it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```